# Web Intelligence : display array depending month

Tags: business-objects, webi

I start in Business Object and Webi and i try to display an array of values depending of month.

I created a variable in function of the month to get my values :

---

=Number([Nume]) In ([Libe]) Where ([Dcom] = [Month])

---

I want my users to select the variable "Month" in an option input as "January", "February", ...
I don't know how to declare my variable at the beginning to change it after, should i declare it with a default one ? How i configure the control panel with this ?

I work on Web Intelligence 4.2 Support Pack 4 Compilation : 14.2.4.2410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you create an input control based on a Month variable you should be able to do what you want.

So let's begin by creating a variable named **Month** and set its value to nothing (blank or ="")...

[image]

Next create an input control based on that Month variable. You will need to click on the **Input Controls** icon on the left and then click **New**. You could also drag Month onto your report and then right-click and choose "Filter by a New input control".

[image]

Click on the ellipses (...) button associated with List of Values to create your list of month names...

[image]

Get rid of "[EMPTY_VALUE]" and add in the months. You can add them all at once as a semi-colon separated string (January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December).

[image]

Click **OK** and then **Finish**.

Now your selection of a value for your Month variable will be used in whatever other formulas you have. To show this in action I'll create a variable name **VisibleFlag**.

```
VisibleFlag=If([Month Name] = [Variables].[Month] Or [Variables].[Month] = ""; 1; 0)
```

I could then filter on VisibleFlag=1 to only display data where Month Name from the eFashion universe is equal to the month I choose or to display all data if no month is specified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an array-type filter like that.  The closest you can get is an **Input Control**, which is an interactive filter than applies to a dimension and can optionally apply to one or more blocks in the report.